# Return type for a function that returns an object with both fixed and variable keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm converting an existing codebase to TypeScript and am going in circles with one particular function.

The goal is to return an object that has a `byID` key that holds key/value pairs of generic type T and an arbitrary amount of additional fields that each hold an array of strings.

My current approach is:

```
function generateEmptyState<T>(additionalFields: string[] = []): {byID: {[key: string]: T}, [key: typeof additionalFields[number]]: string[]} {
  return {
    byID: {},
    ...additionalFields.reduce((a,b) => ({...a, [b]: []}), {}),
  }
}

type Post = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    authorID: string;
    tag: string;
}

const posts = generateEmptyState<Post>(['byAuthorID', 'byTag']);
// Expected type: { byID: {[key: string]: Post }, byAuthorID: string[], byTag: string[] };
```

But I run into 2 errors:
`TS2411: Property  byID  of type  { [key: string]: T; }  is not assignable to  string  index type  string[]`

and

```
TS2322: Type  { byID: {}; }  is not assignable to type
{ [key: string]: string[]; byID: { [key: string]: T; }; }
Property  byID is incompatible with index signature.
```

It seems that the type for `byID` is always overwritten by the typing for the `...additionalFields`.

Any ideas for how to resolve this?

Comment: That type doesn't mean what you want; `typeof additionalFields[number]` is just `string`. You need to add another type parameter `K` for that, but then you run into [ms/TS#26242](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) since you apparently need to manually specify `T` but let the compiler infer `K`. The closest you're going to get here is to use currying, as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/mMLGzN). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It set me in the right direction and I think I've managed to [figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181877/5839360). My main issue was that `typeof additionalFields[number]` should have been something more like `[K in F[number]]`. I also needed to repeat myself in explicitly passing that second parameter.

Comment: Am I to understand that you used my suggestion to figure out how to proceed, but instead of letting me write up my answer explaining as mentioned, you wrote up your own answer without an explanation and without attribution? That's your prerogative, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. I am still willing to write things up. If you'd rather just use your own answer, though, would you mind editing to to actually explain how it works and also give proper attribution?

Comment: I posted what I'd done since I wasn't sure you'd want to write up a full answer if it was already resolved. I'll gladly remove my reply & mark yours as the accepted one if you want to post it. No harm intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the type of `additionalFields` is just `string[]` no matter what. So `typeof additionalFields[number]` is just a compicated way to write `string`.  If you want to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements of the `additionalFields` argument, you'll need the function to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type.

So the first step would be to add another type parameter to represent the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of elements of `additionalFields`; let's call that `K` (since they will be used as keys) in the output type:

```
function generateEmptyState<T, K extends string>(
  additionalFields: K[] = []
) {
  return {
    byID: {} as { [key: string]: T },
    ...(additionalFields.reduce(
      (a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]: [] }), {}) as { [P in K]: string[] }
    )
  }
}
```

The return type of that function is `{ byID: { [key: string]: T } } & { [P in K]: string[] }`, which accurately represents the type you want.  The type `{[P in K]: string[]}` is equivalent to `Record<K, string[]>` (using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) and means "a type where each key of type `K` has a value of type `string[]`.

---

Unfortunately you cannot use this easily.  If you try to call it the way you wanted:

```
const posts = generateEmptyState<Post>(['byAuthorID', 'byTag']);
// error, expected 2 type arguments, got one
```

you get an error. The function takes *two* type arguments now, and you only passed one.  You could manually specify both:

```
const posts = generateEmptyState<Post, 'byAuthorID' | 'byTag'>(['byAuthorID', 'byTag']);
/* const posts: {
    byID: {
        [key: string]: Post;
    };
} & {
    byAuthorID: string[];
    byTag: string[];
}) */
```

and that works. It's exactly the type you want. But now you're writing out your `additionalFields` elements twice, which is redundant.

---

Ideally you'd like the compiler to allow you to just write out the argument for `T` as `<Post>` and then it would *infer* the argument for `K`. That is, you'd like *partial type argument inference*. But TypeScript doesn't currently support that. There's a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), but there's no indication that it will be implemented anytime soon.

Until and unless that happens you'll need to work around it. You could either just manually specify both types as shown above.  Or you could refactor. The most common refactoring I use is to split the single function into two via [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). You call the generic function with a manually specified type argument, and then it returns another generic function which infers the remaining type argument.  It looks like this:

```
function generateEmptyState<T>() {
  return function <K extends string>(
    additionalFields: K[] = []
  ) {
    return {
      byID: {} as { [key: string]: T },
      ...(additionalFields.reduce(
        (a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]: [] }), {}) as { [P in K]: string[] }
      )
    }
  }
}

const posts = generateEmptyState<Post>()(['byAuthorID', 'byTag']);
```

This requires an extra `()` when you use it, but you're not being redundant with your elements. Currying is especially useful if you think you're going to be reusing `generateEmptyState<Post>` a lot.  Then you can just give that a name and reuse it:

```
const generateEmptyPostState = generateEmptyState<Post>();
const posts1 = generateEmptyPostState(['byAuthorID', 'byTag']);
const posts2 = generateEmptyPostState(['abc', 'def', 'ghi']);
const posts3 = generateEmptyPostState([]);
```

Another refactoring is to add a dummy function argument of the type you would have normally manually specified as a type argument.  Something like this:

```
function generateEmptyState<T, K extends string>(
  t: T, additionalFields: K[] = []
) {
  return {
    byID: {} as { [key: string]: T },
    ...(additionalFields.reduce(
      (a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]: [] }), {}) as { [P in K]: string[] }
    )
  }
}

const posts = generateEmptyState(
  null! as Post,
  ['byAuthorID', 'byTag']
);
```

Now you have to pass in a `Post` argument if you have one. If you don't, you can just lie to the compiler about it by [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that some random thing is a `Post`. The tersest way to do that is `null! as Post` since `null!` is a [non-null asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) `null`, which is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), and you can assign `never` to anything. It works, but it's weird... weirder than currying.

I'd only do this if you actually have a value of type `Post` sitting around and if `generateEmptyState`'s implementation could possibly use it instead of just ignoring it.  That doesn't seem to be the case here, but there are other use cases where this is reasonable.

---

So there you go. The basic answer here is "add another generic type parameter" but then, in the absence of partial type argument inference, you have to decide which of the various workarounds you'd like to use.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=10&pln=18&pc=68#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkgC4CeMyACgPZQlIC8eRxSAlgCYBcS9ATu2ABzANytiJdiQwReAoWIlJ4NYCQjr5JQSPFskIAK4kAFjX4BJACLbdSgyRDC7i-UgC+rUJFgJkAGLs-PQAyuYMBMoAZkbA8FJqSMKaEPwgGgCiYDDkoU4aADwAKgA0SADSSBAAHhrAnFB8OooAfAAUysQgnJzS7GqYQRAYjbwVANoAukxI08oAlCwGxPwQJEb8wMsrxABGZDa8uB6GTbhzANYQZK4iU7zFnqVdbAB0H+09fYmgGMOjKBvNacIyITq7Axfcp7JaMVpIdoXD5vEDlCZ7B5zGYeBblE5LEDnOZUDjbCpYhQiaaeV7EBavLwGJlsFLANIZCDZXJkfKcwq0egdCYAcgOAEETOYrNYReUxWRis4RVMFu5iAB6DXVfj8CzlWqUBIQThIABMpAoyBA-GERkg6ig5WENAYaggyjZHKyOTyBQgAroJHlEqlFhsIqQAB8kAqlcIRcKFZKzOHZSHFcrVeqkFqkDRLiAyDCTEh2SammALMh6EZotFCMQvN5wNA4IgkABhTb8MiKFgxOIJAbbL3pH08vlFYodJYEXZrDZbJCxeK-JCFKq1eqNZr2Dp0wy9fqDf7sEZjSo05jzXZzw+LzbbeeQ-aHWx4U5EvBXG53YRYk8HgvK+xAol8x6-EM56AsCJpghAEKgcQ0JILCTAIkiSAomicyYrwNK4viuJnD+EykkIlSUi01I4oe9KHiyzLKM2yiqMA9BIDAQZNMwY6ctyfr8oKJCzu0oqhqmMpyrGBzxiqarKBqABUSBsWonHcfQUDHIeBxHDsyETNctx7ooWIiTmzI5qcABkhkrJJ0oGVSwjTFZbByc4-7uSxDIGMpGqNmw7GcfxE7kCJU7IHxqTjlyvq8v6gZCu0ikGKFDBaSQUAAIyzOFCU8lF-ricmYbSRm8nZupHFZTxFqxey8WCWQJWcmVIB7PAMkipwEDRL1wimOwCk5plXE8QAzAVcUCYl7UaOJNWsM2xA+G2-hINY9pgH2IgDgYq7DkkhWtdFJTlFudSaLurkHrsJCPOU3wnn8AKXpMMw3lMiwOas6xPv9nnvscX7EsZf5mfcjzPIe4GvVBZ4XkCIIIUhr6oeh8KIsiHy4RiWKEXin6EhDFHktR9iEYe-krExtIZRp9XabNzXzZOpWvMARgYBgACEpEiSBKwSWQKbOemsmZgmv0GOlbAqWpTN1ZN2m6a++kfi+Rkmf+FlBh5TY2Ug9k6454sVS5NFuVMRtoTLPl235yiBathAeEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a bit more verbose, but this seems to do the trick:

```
type ArrayToObjectType<T, F extends string[]> = {
    byID: {[key: string]: T};
} & {
    [K in F[number]]: string[];
}

export function generateEmptyState<T, F extends string[]>(additionalFields: F): ArrayToObjectType<T, F> {
    return {
        byID: {},
        ...additionalFields.reduce((obj, key) => (
            {...obj, [key]: []}
        ), {} as {[K in F[number]]: string[]}),
    };
}

type Post = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    authorID: string;
    tag: string;
}

const posts = generateEmptyState<Post, ['byAuthorID', 'byTag']>(['byAuthorID', 'byTag']);

const byID = posts.byID; // {[p: string]: Post}
const byAuthorID = posts.byAuthorID; // string[]
const byTag = posts.byTag; // string[]
```